# Using PHP tags inside of href="" definition

Tags: php, html-table, directory, include, root

I'm using a simple solution for getting the server root and it works quite well with my includes:

```
<?php $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/frizkie'; ?>
```

I'm doing some tables, and the .php file that contains the table is nested quite a few directories down at:

```
/main/tools/planners.php
```

My images are located in:

```
/images/staticons/
```

And my code looks like:

```
<td onClick="document.location.href='planners/agility.php';">Contents</a></td>
```

I'd like to be able to use the $root directory for the 'planners/agility.php' part, but doing so like this:

```
onClick="document.location.href='<?php echo $root; ?>/planners/agility.php';"
```

Causes the onClick part to not work at all. On top of this, I'd also like to define table cell backgrounds using the same method, using the `$root` variable. I've tried using PHP tags in the background="" definition, but the images don't show in Chrome or Firefox - only IE9.

Comment: view file source is the var shown?

Comment: `<td class="borderhighlight" background="C:/xampp/htdocs/frizkie/images/staticons/agil.gif" onclick="document.location.href='C:/xampp/htdocs/frizkie/main/tools/planners/agility.php';">`

That's from the source view on IE9. Looks fine to me, but I can't click the cell and follow the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is for server-side pathing so to speak, as you already noted. You don't need to put it in your markup, CSS and JS. I'd stick with absolute-relative paths like `/images/background.jpg` (note the leading slash). That way even if your page is accessed by a URL like

`http://example.com/blog/123-my-beautiful-post/`

the image is downloaded from

`http://example.com/images/background.jpg`

and not

`http://example.com/images/blog/123-my-beautiful-post/images/background.jpg`.

Using `DOCUMENT_ROOT` helps a lot when including multiple files scattered around your document root - using relative paths here gives me a headache. If you really want full urls in your pages, though, you can try using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` for that matter, but I really don't understand the need to do so.

Comment: I think I tried to make it more complicated than necessary, and probably did something wrong in the past to make me think that starting a path with a backslash didn't automatically go to the root directory. I think I got confused because my local server file heirarchy is structured differently in relation to the root of the webserver (localhost vs domain.com). Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing HTML markup, don't use server paths in your hrefs. Instead, the hrefs should be relative from the base of your website domain.

Use document root when you want to load PHP files via require/require_once/include/include_once.

Also, the reason why your code didn't work is likely because on some web server installations, one of three conditions exist for document root (set in Apache httpd.conf):

1. It isn't set
2. There is a trailing slash
3. There is no trailing slash

So you have to check for all three conditions and then decide, say, to always have a trailing slash.

If it isn't set, you should set a $docroot explicitly to a defined constant like define("DOCROOT", "/user/home/jayleno/") and then use that throughout your code.

```
$docRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
if (strlen($docRoot) <= 0) {
   // you are going to have to hard code it
   $docRoot = "/usr/home/jayleno/";
}
$lastChar = substr($docRoot, -1);
if ($lastChar != '\\' || $lastChar != '/')
   $docRoot .= "/";

$templateRoot = $docRoot . "templates/";
$moduleRoot = $docRoot . "modules/";
.
.
$rootCanal = $docRoot . "mytootheaches/";
```